# Adding pages between title and abstract

Tags: abstract

I want to add set of pages between the title and the abstract

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Title}
\author[add1]{ME}
\ead{m@test.com}
\begin{abstract}
this is the abstract
\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
keyword
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}
\section{Introduction}
    Introduction 
\end{document}
```

When I write anything before abstract it shows at the beginning of the document. 
I actually need to add long **colored** text that spans over two pages or more before the abstract and below the title information.

Comment: If you plan to submit this article to a publisher, they might reject your 'non-standard' behaviour, i.e. having a page break between title and abstract

Comment: Actually, the editor asked me to insert the response of their review between the title and the introduction.

Comment: The frontmatter environment in elsearticle is just a sneaky way of adding \maketitle.  More to the point, \abstract desn't actually write anything, it just stores the contents for \maketitle to format.